# records with same first and Last names

Tags: oracle11g

I have EMP table with following columns:

```
EmpID
firstName
LastName
Age
DOB
status
```

How do I get all the employees with the same FirstName and LastName

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want your output to look like

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, count(*)
  FROM emp
 GROUP BY firstName, lastName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

will show you all the firstName and lastName pairs that are duplicated.  If you want to get the empID of both duplicated rows (assuming neither firstName nor lastName can be NULL)

```
SELECT a.empID, b.empID
  FROM emp a,
       emp b
 WHERE a.firstName = b.firstName
   AND a.lastName  = b.lastName
   AND a.rowid     > b.rowid
```